# hosting a wamp database on www.000webhost.com, showing jsonparsing error in android

Tags: android, wamp, web-hosting, arrays

I am done with my time table application where in time tables are stored in wamp server,and my android app shall fetch the tables and save them in sqlite DB on android.I used Jsonparsing to  get the data from server.

I  failed to host my tables on www.000webhost.com,In android logcat i am getting warnings and errors on Json parsing.

On browsing i got to know that, the php i used in wamp is 3.4 but in above website its 3.2 and it does not support json arrays.

Is there any way to solve this problem? are there any other free websites to host that support 
Json arrays?

Here is my part of code..

```
private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();;

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        Dialog.show();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DEPT",DEPT));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SEM",SEM));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DIV",DIV));
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
       try{
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
              httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
              response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
              inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              Dialog.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

          }


       return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
    {
         try{
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
             json = sb.toString();
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
          }
       try{
           JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(json);
        SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb", MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stores;");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stores(day VARCHAR,first VARCHAR,sec VARCHAR," +
                "third VARCHAR,fourth VARCHAR,fifth VARCHAR,sixth VARCHAR," +
                "seventh VARCHAR,eighth VARCHAR);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO stores VALUES('DAY','8-9','9-10','10:15-11:15','11:15-12:15'," +
                "'12:30-1:30','1:30-2:30','2:45-3:45','3:45-4:45');");
           for (int i=0; i < (jarray.length()); i++)
           {
             JSONObject oneObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
          SQLiteDatabase db1=openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb", MODE_PRIVATE,null);

          db1.execSQL("INSERT INTO stores ( day,first,sec,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth) " +
                "VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,? )",
                new Object [] {
               strday = oneObject.getString("day"),
               strone = oneObject.getString("8-9"),
               strtwo = oneObject.getString("9-10"),
               strthree = oneObject.getString("10:15-11:15"),
               strfour = oneObject.getString("11:15-12:15"),
               strfive = oneObject.getString("12:30-1:30"),
               strsix = oneObject.getString("1:30-2:30"),
               strseven = oneObject.getString("2:45-3:45"),
               streight = oneObject.getString("3:45-4:45")
        }
                  );
        db1.close();
        Dialog.dismiss(); 
           }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           db.close();

       }
       catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         Log.e("log_tag", "oops!! error in saving"+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "oops!! error in saving ur  time table", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your Time Table is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    }
}
public void grabURL(String url)
{
    new GrabURL().execute(url);
}
```

log cat....

```
12-18 18:27:59.373: W/KeyCharacterMap(1014): No keyboard for id 0
12-18 18:27:59.373: W/KeyCharacterMap(1014): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-18 18:28:37.283: D/dalvikvm(1014): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 167K, 51% free 2716K/5511K, external 513K/517K, paused 51ms
12-18 18:28:38.643: D/dalvikvm(1014): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 66K, 50% free 2827K/5639K, external 518K/1030K, paused 47ms
12-18 18:28:39.363: W/System.err(1014): org.json.JSONException: Value Invalid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
12-18 18:28:39.363: W/System.err(1014):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
12-18 18:28:39.363: W/System.err(1014):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
12-18 18:28:39.363: W/System.err(1014):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
12-18 18:28:39.363: W/System.err(1014):     at com.exam.allabouttable.MainActivity$GrabURL.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:195)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at com.exam.allabouttable.MainActivity$GrabURL.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 18:28:39.373: W/System.err(1014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-18 18:28:39.383: W/System.err(1014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-18 18:28:39.383: W/System.err(1014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-18 18:28:39.383: W/System.err(1014):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 18:28:39.383: E/log_tag(1014): oops!! error in savingorg.json.JSONException: Value Invalid of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
12-18 18:36:29.023: I/dalvikvm(1014): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
```

Comment: Could you share the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Tom Cammann I shared logcat report.. please check it

Comment: free host have some problem,see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602213/connect-android-to-server-in-free-webhost/31602353#31602353

Answer (score 0):

From your logs it just appears that the String you are passing to `new JSONArray()` is not valid JSON. Make sure your the string is valid, perhaps print it out before you pass it in just to check it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i just solved my problem which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983697/couldnt-connect-to-database-with-android/20011651?noredirect=1#20011651)

I've changed the HttpPost to HttpGet, for retrieving data.