# Couldn't Connect to Database with Android

Tags: java, php, android, database

I am trying to execute the following code for retrieving data from database using web services:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getData();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void getData(){
    TextView resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://HOSTNAME/FILENAME.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
    }
    //converting to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result"+ e.toString());
    }

    //parse data
    try{
        String s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + "St.ID" + json.getString("StId") + "\n " +json.getString("StName") + "\n" + json.getString("StMail");

        }
        resultView.setText(s);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Log_tage", "Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());
    }
}
```

But an error returns : Couldn't connect to database.

And here's the output LogCat:

11-14 20:10:35.057: E/log_tag(5323): Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

11-14 20:10:35.057: E/log_tag(5323): Error converting resultjava.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

11-14 20:10:35.057: E/Log_tage(5323): Error Parsing Dataorg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0

I've added a php file on some web service and it's working well, but i think it's about the HttpPost URL, is there a specific format for the HttpPost URL or is it just the same URL as given in the web service ?

**PHP file:**

```
   <?php 
$con = mysql_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not Connect:'. mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db("database_name",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       $output[]=$row;
    }

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Please help with that.

Comment: `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost)`

The above should be executed in a `thread` or `AsyncTask`. You should not run network related operation on the ui thread.

Comment: Can you possibly post the error details as well? You can print errors to LogCat easily via `.e("Tag", "Message", exception)`.

Comment: @Raghunandan, how is that ?, am sorry i am new to android programming, and where to put the AsyncTask exactly?!

Comment: @Izzo32 check the docs get to know about asynctask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @Pietu1998, This is the LogCat : 

11-14 20:10:35.057: E/log_tag(5323): Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException


11-14 20:10:35.057: E/log_tag(5323): Error converting resultjava.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null


11-14 20:10:35.057: E/Log_tage(5323): Error Parsing Dataorg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: @Izzo32 Just put that in the question. It doesn't even fit in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved and data retrieved by using @Carlo 's code and editing the following line of code:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://HOSTNAME/FILENAME.php");
```

to:

```
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://HOSTNAME/FILENAME.php");
```

as mentioned in my code, i wanted to retrieve data from the URL not posting data.

HttpPost > used for submitting data to a specified resource.
HttpGet > used for retrieving data from a specified resource.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific format for the HttpPost URL, it is just the same URL as given in the web service.

You must use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to solve the "Couldn't connect to database" error.

Here is your code using AsynTask, also you have to set the text of the `TextView` in the `onPostExecute` method, like shown:

```
RetrievingDataFromDatabase retrievingTask;
TextView resultView;
String s;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    retrievingTask = new RetrievingDataFromDatabase();
    retrievingTask.execute((Void) null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getData(){
    resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try { 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://HOSTNAME/FILENAME.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
    }
    //converting to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    //parse data
    try {
        s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + "St. ID" + json.getString("StId") + "\n " + json.getString("StName") + "\n" + json.getString("StMail");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Log_tage", "Error Parsing Data" + e.toString());
    }
}

class RetrievingDataFromDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        resultView.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Carlo, i did what you said am getting a new error:

Error Parsing Dataorg.json.JSONException: Value <HTML>< of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

i'll post my php file, please check it in the question