# Error Parsing Data, JSON

Tags: java, android, database, json

I am trying to execute a small android app to get data from database that's hosted on web service, having the following bulk of code but am getting some errors.

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView Name;
TextView ID;
TextView Email;
private static String url = "http://HostName/GetData.php";
private static final String TAG_Name = "Name";
private static final String TAG_ID = "Id";
private static final String TAG_Email = "Email";

JSONArray user = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new JSONParse().execute();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        ID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
               // Getting JSON Array
               user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Name);
               JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

               // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
               String Name1 = c.getString(TAG_Name);
               String ID1 = c.getString(TAG_ID);
               String Email1 = c.getString(TAG_Email);

               //Set JSON Data in TextView
               Name.setText(Name1);
               ID.setText(ID1);
               Email.setText(Email1);

       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }

}
 }
```

**JSONParser.java:**

```
 public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

}

i am having the following LogCat:

[image: LogCat]

**PHP File :**

```
<?php
header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');
$con = mysql_connect("***","***","***");

if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not Connect:' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db("database_name",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database_name");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       $output[]=$row;
    }

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

PHP response is :

[{"Name":"Izzo32","Id":"5554","Email":"xxx@hotmail.com"}]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse JSON, then you should provide JSON, not html. Apparently you are receiving an "< html >" tag!

If I was you, I'd fix my webservice and use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert json to java objects!

Comment: what is your webservice response? can you paste it here?

Comment: the PHP response is posted already in the question and I've solved a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983697/couldnt-connect-to-database-with-android), Thank you :)

Comment: but the error code says it is getting a <html> tag... did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trying to turn a non-JSON formatted string into a json object thats whats causing your error. You should print out the html response to see the whole thing and post that on here.

Comment: But what is the string you are trying to turn into a json Object. Maybe its inside the html brackets

Comment: Sorry i didn't get that! :/

Comment: Take the string you are trying to convert into a json array or json object and print it to the log cat. from there you can see if it has html brackets inside of if it or if its malformed.

Comment: i've done this, and you can find the LogCat in the question, i guess it has an html brackets but i don't know how to handle this situation!

Comment: Maybe try removing the header() declaration from the top of your php. I dont think in any scripts that I return json to a client I use that. The only time I do that is when Im using php to return images or files.

Comment: i removed the header(). am getting a new error which is : 

Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Comment: What does the entire response look like

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the question again, I'm pretty sure my expertise is of little use. Sorry.