# Connect android to server in free webhost

Tags: php, android, mysql

Can I connect an android app to server in free webhost like (www.000webhost.com) and send data between android and mysql database and php?

If so, can anyone give me some tutorial to do this?

Comment: Work via api, see this: http://hayageek.com/android-http-post-get/

Comment: @user5148365 I've got the perfect answer you can see

Comment: (Voting to close as too broad. Stack Overflow is more suited to _specific_ problems, rather than requests for tutorials).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can but have small problem for get data,for example

PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
$hostname='mysql2.000webhost.com';
$username='a3067857_admin';
$password='xxxxxxxxx';
$response = array();
try {

    $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=a7769372_db",$username  ,$password);

    $response["allname"] = array();

    /*** QUERY ****/
    $sql='SELECT * FROM my_table';

    $stmt=$dbh->query($sql);

    $objs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach($objs as $object) {
        $news = array();        
        $news["id"]=$object->id;
        $news["Name"]=$object->name;

        array_push($response["allname"], $news);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

    /*** close connection ***/
    $dbh=null;

}catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

My output:

```
{"allname":[{"id":"1","Name":"sadegh"},{"id":"2","Name":"saleh"}]}
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Free hosts have small problem it show a script in output. You must remove the script in output and the remaining part will be stored in a variable then use this variable to get data from JSON.

First most people will remove this code:

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

For example, I use GetData() to get data from PHP file and remove the additional code:

```
public void GetData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://sheikhoo.net46.net/getname.php");
            Log.i("LOG", "HttpPost -> getname.php");
            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            Log.i("LOG", inputStream + "," + result);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.i("LOG", result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
                Log.i("LOG", " error ");
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            Log.i("LOG", " result: " + result);
            /*****************remove script***********************/
            String s = result;
            int position = s.indexOf("}]}"); 

            s=s.substring(0, position + 3);
            /****************************************************/
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            Log.i("LOG", " onPostExecute -> " + result );
            myJSON=result;
            Log.i("LOG", "myJSON" + myJSON);
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    Log.i("LOG", " GetDataJSON " );
    g.execute();
}
```

Now you can extract data from `myJSON` variable

**myJSON :**

```
{"allname":[{"id":"1","Name":"sadegh"},{"id":"2","Name":"saleh"}]}
```

---

Full code to get data from php and show in listview:

First you need add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to **AndroidManifest.xml** for connect internet.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.sheikhoo.freehost"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then add `list_item.xml` to project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and add listview to `activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ir.sheikhoo.freehost.MainActivity" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in `MainActivity.java` get data with `GetData()` and show data to ListView with `ShowNameList()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String myJSON;

    private static final String TAG_ALLNAME="allname";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";

    JSONArray jname = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nameList;

    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("LOG", "Start <-- ");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        nameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        Log.i("LOG", "GetData <-- ");

        GetData();
    }

    public void GetData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://sheikhoo.net46.net/getname.php");
                Log.i("LOG", "HttpPost -> getname.php");
                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                Log.i("LOG", inputStream + "," + result);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                    Log.i("LOG", result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                    Log.i("LOG", " error ");
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                Log.i("LOG", " result: " + result);
                /*****************remove script***********************/
                String s = result;
                int position = s.indexOf("}]}"); 

                s=s.substring(0, position + 3);
                /****************************************************/
                return s;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                Log.i("LOG", " onPostExecute -> " + result );
                myJSON=result;
                Log.i("LOG", "myJSON" + myJSON);
                //
                ShowNameList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        Log.i("LOG", " GetDataJSON " );
        g.execute();
    }

    protected void ShowNameList(){
        try {
            Log.i("LOG", " showList " );
            //if(myJSON!=null){
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                jname = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_ALLNAME);

                for(int i=0;i<jname.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c = jname.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    Log.i("Ekhteraat app ControlPanel", id);

                    HashMap<String,String> lname = new HashMap<String,String>();

                    lname.put(TAG_ID,id);
                    lname.put(TAG_NAME,name);

                    nameList.add(lname);
                //}

                    Log.i("LOG", "Name -> " + id + " " +  name);
                    //setNewNews;
                    ;

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, nameList, R.layout.list_item,
                            new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME},
                            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name}
                    );
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Picture:

[image: use Free host]

For send data to MySQL, first make PHP code to insert data to MySQL.

(» i add message to show what happen in app)

PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');

$hostname='mysql2.000webhost.com';
$username='a3067857_admin';
$password='xxxxxxxxx';

try {

    $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=a7769372_db;charset=utf8mb4",$username,$password);


    /*** QUERY ****/

    $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO a7769372_db.my_table (name) VALUES (:Name);");

    if ($statement->execute(array(':Name' => $_POST['Name']))) {
        echo "executed";
    } else {
        echo "not executed";
    }

    /*** close connection ***/
    $dbh=null;

}catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Create table in MySQL

**»** because we just send name, so id should be `AUTO_INCREMENT` in phpMyAdmin.

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

[image: mysql]

then make new Activity and add `EditText`,`Button`

activity_send.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ir.sheikhoo.freehost.SendActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name :" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SendActivity.java:

```
public class SendActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText ed_name;

    String myJSON;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send);

        ed_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!ed_name.getText().toString().matches("")){
                    SendData();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Name NULL",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void SendData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            private ProgressDialog Dialog;
            private InputStream is = null;
            private String url = "http://sheikhoo.net46.net/sendname.php";
            private String page_output = "";

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                super.onPreExecute();
                Dialog = new ProgressDialog(SendActivity.this);
                Dialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
                Dialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
                Dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                Dialog.setCancelable(true);
                Dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                try {
                        // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", ed_name.getText().toString()));
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error To Connect",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error To Connect",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error To Connect",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                page_output = sb.toString();

                Log.i("LOG", "page_output --> " + page_output); ///<--------------------------|
            /*****************remove script***********************/
            String s = page_output;
            int position = s.indexOf("<"); 

            s=s.substring(0, position - 1);

            page_output=s;
            /****************************************************/
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Buffer Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return page_output;
        }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                Dialog.dismiss();

                Log.i("LOG", " onPostExecute -> " + result );
                myJSON=result;
                Log.i("LOG", "myJSON" + myJSON);

                if(myJSON.trim().equals("executed")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Name Save in DB",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ed_name.setText("");
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error Name don't Save in DB",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        Log.i("LOG", " GetDataJSON " );
        g.execute();
    }
}
```

Picture:

[image: MySQL]

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments here insofar I think they were obsolete now. Please use *chat* in future, comments are not really for extended discussion.

Comment: @sadegh…  I down the project…  I try it without editing….  Not work…..  Is this project u use to send name to my database when u log to my account?

Comment: No I use AIDE on mobile….  But I install the app in bin folder in your project and try… ..doesnt work

Comment: Your project log and my project log? I dont understand u… .. What u mean

Comment: In this time u install sendfreehost.apk from bin folder in your project….  Try to send name…. Doesnt work

Comment: Your project doesnt work

Comment: @sadegh… .AIDE dont show log….  I try to use apk file in your project .. Doesnt work

Comment: Sadegh do you send name "ali reza" to my database?

Comment: I down it….  I sent name (ibrahim) to your database…  its insert into your database???

Comment: Ok sadegh..  I think the problem in my phone….  I login to net via wifi using router….  Is it related with send data from android to mysql?  I try 20 app for send data to mysql and all doesnt work…  thank u

Comment: OK :) ,I think it is better delete all comments